# SDL2 "skip" frames when mouse no moving

Tags: c++, animation, sdl-2

I'm trying to make some animation with SDL2.
SDL2 has some bad performance, and my simple chess game was running at 10fps.

I don't want to redraw the whole screen every frames, it takes way to long. So in order to optimize my game I decided to code an Animation class ( a simple fade in/out effect) which only redraw some part of the screen everyframe (basicly redraw the selected piece)

```cpp
void myGame::sdlLoop() {
    SDL_Event events;
    bool quit = false;


    while (!quit) {
        bool redraw = false; //We assume we don't want to redraw everything (yet)
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&events)) {
            switch (events.key.keysym.scancode) {
                ....

            }
            if(redraw) draw(); // Only redraw whole screen IF NEEDED
            else drawAnimations(); // Better use that for better performance
        }
    }
}

void myGame::drawAnimations(){

    int i = 0;
    while(i < arr.size()){
        ....
        drawThingsAtCertainsPixels(now_time, animation_start_time, animation_duration); //Basicly a simple fade effect, something like
                     //pixelColor = color1 * advancement + color2 * (1 - advancement) 
    }


    // Show the window
    SDL_RenderPresent( m_renderer );
}
```

So far so good, but I noticed a weird behavior.
The animation is "jerky", most of the frames are skipped
I ended up avec all of my fadeout unfinished because the last frame where skipped.
**But**, when I constantly move the mouse, everything goes right and no frame are dropped

I think it is linked to SDL wanting to optimize performance, and only run at 100% speed when someting important is going on (user inputting things or windows interacted).

**Do you know why is this happening, and how to fix that ?**
 I mean how to have SDL2 computing every frame even if I don't move the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a bit guilty for finding the solution right after posting this question (but I swear I tore my hair out a lot)

The solution is quite simple

```
while (!quit) {
    bool redraw = false; //We assume we don't want to redraw everything (yet)
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&events)) {
        switch (events.key.keysym.scancode) {
            ....
        }
        if(redraw) draw(); // Only redraw whole screen IF NEEDED
        else drawAnimation(); // Better use that for better performance
    }
}
```

Just move the drawAnimations() function a bit lower, out of the while (SDL_PollEvent(&events)) {

```
while (!quit) {
    bool redraw = false; //We assume we don't want to redraw everything (yet)
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&events)) {
        switch (events.key.keysym.scancode) {
            ....
        }
    }
    if(redraw) draw(); // Only redraw whole screen IF NEEDED
    else drawAnimation(); // Better use that for better performance
}
```